# What is the difference between "constructor based injection" and " autowire by constructor mode" in Spring

Tags: spring, autowired

I know and understand constructor based injection. But, the autowiring modes confuse me. 
1) I have read that default mode for autowiring is 'no autowiring' i.e. We have to manually set the properties in xml file. But, isn't xml based configuration a type of autowiring? How can it be considered 'No autowiring'?
2) Other modes for autowiring are i) byName ii) byType iii)constructor iv) auto-detect. Am i correct to assume the following:

a) When using xml configuration based autowiring, the default mode is 'byName'(i.e. I have to keep the name of property reference the same as the name of the bean which is being used as a property.)

b) When using Annotations, default mode is 'byType'( Regardless of the place the @Autowired keyword is placed i.e on the setter, on the constructor or on the property, it will search the type of the property being autowried)

3) What is the difference between constructor based injection and 'constructor' mode of autowiring?(I have read that constructor mode means it applies byType mode on all the constructor arguments, but how is it different from placing @Autowired keyword on the constructor)

4) I know that to enable autowired mode byName in annotations, in the bean definition in the xml file, I have to use " autowire = 'byName' ". But, suppose I am using Annotations only config( using @Component, and no bean definitions in the xml ), and I want to use byName autowire mode, then what is the way of doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused. First, you need to understand dependency injection (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)). There is ton of info about DI but in short, it means some third party (e.g spring IOC) passes the dependencies to the objects rather than the objects to create/obtain the references themselves. This could happen either through constructor or setter. For instance, consider constructor DI

```
class B{
}

class A{
  private B b;
  public A(B b){
    this.b = b;
  } 
}
```

Some third party will inject an instance of class B into A rather class A create a reference to B itself. Very often you would use an interface so class A wouldn't even know what object will be injected into it.

Now in Spring there are different ways to configure these associations between the objects (the example above). You can either use XML, Java Config or Autowiring. They are independent but do the same stuff.

In both XML and JAVA config you need to configure the dependencies explicitly - either in xml file or having a @Configuration class for the JAVA Config and annotating the beans with @Bean. The autowiring is different. There you create simple POJOs which you annotate with @Component, @Controller, @Service or @Repository. They will be automatically registered as beans via component scanning. With autowiring you don't need to explicitly configure the dependencies in XML file or JAVA Config class. You can do it in code directly. For instance, if we have to compare java config vs autowiring using the previous example

```
Java Config (explicit config in a config class)

@Bean
public A getA(){
  return new A(new B());
}

Autowiring (implicit - done in code)

   @Component 
   class B{
   }

@Component
class A{
  private B b;

  @Autowired
  public A(B b){
    this.b = b;
  } 
}
```

In the latter we autowire class B into class A (they both will be registered as beans due to @Component annotation) without having explicitly defined this association in an xml file or java config class. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: It was very helpful to understand the difference between the two.Thanks. UserF40 and you clarified most of my questions. A couple remain. Am I correct in assuming that autowiring by constructor is a way of implementing constructor based injection? Also, can u let me know how to use auto detect autowiring mode using annotations and not xml?

Comment: ask another question and you will get the response so that other people can benefit

Comment: Ok.will do that . Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to specify the bean names in the xml, its not happening automatically, hence its not autowiring.

With autowiring spring will figure out what bean to inject even though it may not be explicitly written.

When using xml configuration based autowiring, the default mode is 'byName'

When using Annotations, the ordering that happens depends on the annotation used as there are a few that can be used. `@Autowire` `@Resource` `@Inject`.

When using `@Component`, the default wiring is of type. The method below will resolve on any autowiring needs for a Service object.

```
@Bean
public Service getMyService(){
return new Service();
}
```

If there are multiple `@Bean` methods that return a Service you will get an error.

If you wanted to do wire via name while using `@Component` you would add the `@Qualifier("nameToUse")` annotation to the variable. It would find an `@Bean` annotated method called `getNameToUse()`.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("nameToUse")
private Service myService;
```

Comment: Ok.So,I understand that when we use xml based config,it is not autowiring.But suppose,I am using xml config for bean definitions & annotations for autowiring( i.e I'm not using  @ Component, @ Service,etc)Now, if I place the @ Autowired keyowrd over a property declaration,is it byType? And wht if I place it over a constructor or a setter? (Please note I'm not asking about setter/constructor based injection) This is the link I'm following : http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-core/spring-beans-autowiring-concepts/   Also : http://www.journaldev.com/2623/spring-autowired-annotation

Comment: As mentioned in the answer @Autowire is by type first

Comment: Then , what do we mean by 'autowire by constructor' mode ? I understand byName and byType modes , but not the other two modes namely : ' by constructor ' and ' auto detect' . These are mentioned on the above links.

Comment: By constructor means to not annotate the class properties but the constructor arguments. Auto detect is like scanning where Spring will work out bean candidates.

Comment: So, autowiring by constructor is a way of implementing constructor based injection. Is this statement correct ? Also, can u let me know how to enable auto detect mode using annotation and not mentioning in the xml.?

Comment: Setting variables in a class via manually calling the constructor or autowiring is constructor based injection

Comment: Ok. Thanks much for the help!!